# Trying to avoid parameter overhead in function calls

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

In a performance critical application I am writing, at one point I am repeatedly calling the same function millions of times in a tight loop always with the same parameters.  I decided to try to avoid the overhead of parameter passing by putting the parameters in a class.  For example, before:

```
some_class p1;
some_class p2;
some_class p3;
for (int count = 12345678; count; --count)
    foo(p1,p2,p3);
```

After:

```
class foo         // Ignoring private / public for brevity
{
    some_class& p1_;
    some_class& p2_;
    some_class& p3_;

    foo(some_class& p1, some_class& p2, some_class& p3)
    : p1_(p1), p2_(p2), p3_(p3_)
    {}

    void execute();
 }

some_class p1;
some_class p2;
some_class p3;
foo f(p1,p2,p3);
for (int count = 12345678; count; --count)
    f.execute();
```

My profiling the results were:  Before = 11121 ms, After = 11416ms.

I was expecting a performance improvement because I have avoided pushing the parameter addresses on the stack, but instead got a slight degradation.

Why would this be?  I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition, but I'm thinking that there might be a platform agnostic answer.

Comment: If you're calling it so many times, why not just inline it (either with the `inline` keyword or manually)?

Comment: Compilers are not dumb these days :) Your compiler has probably inlined the function in both cases, figuring that you would save on passing parameters.

Comment: Your function must be really, really tiny in order for pushing three `int` parameters to make a dent on the overall timing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So I suppose by making a class to hold these parameters, OP is preventing the inlining from happening, which in turn has slowed the performance.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante The difference is under 3%, so it could be simply a statistical error in OP's micro-benchmark (these are notoriously imprecise).

Comment: Don't forget now it has to access the underlying objects through a this pointer (at least without optimization). The is an extra layer of indirection, also there could be pointer aliasing issues now; but you don't know unless you look at the assembly. I'm going to assume you're building final and not debug. If the function definition is in the header or the same CPP file the compiler is probably inline this, look at the assembly. If it's not in the same header, look into __forceinline, its the compiler version of the inline keyword, and it's not just a suggestion, it makes it happen.

Comment: dasblinkenlight has a point about the 3%, to verify it's actually slower you might run your test a few more times, maybe for longer with more in the loop, and see if this is really the case.

Comment: It probably passed `p1, p2, p3` in registers anyway. If it knows that these registers are not disturbed by `execute` then it wouldn't need to do that again each loop. Inspecting the generated assembly code would explain.

Answer (score 0):

To completely avoid recalling the function, create some `execute_loop(some_class& p1, some_class& p2, some_class& p3, const int iterations)` (the number of iterations as an extra parameter) and move the loop to inside the function.

---

Some extra reasoning (all probably automated by the compiler from the first optimization level onwards, but hey):

1. The trade for less arguments in your strategy comes with the drawback of class member deference. Your mileage may vary.
2. If the parameters doesn't get modified inside the function, declare them as `const` in the function signature, this indicates to the compiler that the function can just run again without re-reading the arguments.